# How to do conditional operation in java 8 stream to skip next stream operation?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In Traditional way I have written this simple java for loop

```
public String setString(String string) {  
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // This for loop I want to convert into stream. 
    for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
       if (Character.isSpaceChar(c))
           stringBuilder.append(c);
       else if (isBangla(c))
           stringBuilder.append(get(c));
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

String get(int c) {
    return keyMap.getMap((char) c); // Map<Character, String> keyMap
}

boolean isBangla(int codePoint) {
    return ((codePoint >= BANGLA_CHAR_START && codePoint <= BANGLA_CHAR_END) &&
        (codePoint <= BANGLA_NUMBER_START || codePoint >= BANGLA_NUMBER_END)));
}
```

I have tried to something like this.

```
String str = string.chars()
            .filter(i -> Character.isSpaceChar(i)) // if this is true need to add string 
            .filter(this::isBangla)
            .mapToObj(this::get)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

What I am trying to do is if the first filter detect it is a `spaceChar` then it will not do any further stream processing rather it jump into the `collect`.

So how could I achieve this kind of `if/else` situation to skip next stream operation ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't achieve if/else by streams.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes. If it is a spaceChar then I don't need to do check next two operation. However I also need to `map to obj` because it is IntStream. But it is not necessary as you see in my for loop.

Comment: The question is why you want this as a stream at all. Your loop does it correctly and efficiently. In a stream you'll probably need to check if it's a *bangla* twice - once for filtering and once for mapping. So it's less efficient.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I just wonder how could I change that into stream. But I can't find any way out to solve this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you could probably use something like this:

```
String str = string.chars()
           .filter( ch -> Character.isSpaceChar(ch) || isBangla(ch) )
           .mapToObj( ch -> isBangla(ch) ? get(ch) : Character.toString((char)ch))
           .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

As you can see, this stream checks `isBangla` twice. The first time is to leave only characters which are either space or bangla in the stream, the second one in order to know which of them to convert.

Because stream operations are independent - each stream doesn't know what happened in the stream before it - such operations may be more efficient when written in a traditional loop. What's more, you are creating a lot of little strings when you run this in a stream, where you have to convert all characters into strings, not just the bangla ones.

It's important to note that you're not "skipping" anything here. In a traditional loop, you can skip *operations*. But in a stream, skipping *elements* means that they will not be in the final result. What you do in a stream is pass those elements unchanged (or in this case, changed from a `char` to a `String`), not skip.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by `creating lot of little strings` ? From your last paragraph what I understand that all the char converted into string but not added to the final result.

Comment: @seal When you convert the stream to objects, *all* characters become string objects, and only then they are collected. `String` is immutable so the temporary objects are *copied* into the final result. So you have a temporary object created which takes up a little memory and will need to be garbage-collected, which you didn't have when you used `StringBuilder` because you didn't convert it to a `String`, but wrote the character directly into the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: But why all the characters become string objects ? Is not the filter method filtering only the bangla and space char ?

Comment: @seal Yes, I was basically talking about the space characters. In your original loop, they were added to the `StringBuilder` as `char` without any string. In the stream, they are mapped into new string object, and then all the strings - bangla and space strings - are collected.